# Reversibility of the ideal Carnot cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, adiabatic, carnot-cycle

How do adiabatic processes in the reversible Carnot cycle take place? Is the gas adiabatically isolated? If so, how would that happen in real life? (I know that Carnot cycle is not practically possible, but that's rather due to the fact that it would take forever to complete the cycle). If not, the only other way to perform an adiabatic process is by expanding/compressing the gas very fast (so that there is not time to release/receive heat). But if the process is fast, the gas will pass through thermodynamic states that are not equilibrium/steady states, meaning that the cycle would ultimatelly not be reversible.

Comment: With sufficient insulation, the quasi-static idealization and the adiabatic idealization can both be justified, no?

Comment: In addition, mechanical equilibrium (pressure equalization throughout the fluid) happens *very* fast, roughly on the order of the time it takes a sound wave to reach one side of the container to the other (so, governed by the speed of sound in the fluid). Combine the very fast mechanical equilibration with the very slow thermal equilibration (via heat flow through the insulated walls of the container), and it's not too hard to imagine that the process is to a good approximation quasi-static adiabatic.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an insulated vertical cylinder with a massless frictionless piston and a gas inside.  There is a pile of tiny frictionless pebbles sitting on top of the piston to balance the pressure of the gas.  As you slide the first pebble sideways off the top of the piston, the pebble is retained at that elevation, and the gas expands a little (adiabatically) to a new slightly higher elevation.  You do no work in removing the pebble off because the pebbles are frictionless.  Then you gradually remove additional pebbles, allowing the gas to expand to higher elevations.  At the end, the gas has done adiabatic reversible work raising many of the pebbles to a sequence of new higher elevations.

Answer (score 0):

Adiabatically isolated means there would be no way for there to be heat transfer to the environment.

One (theoretical) way this could happen is if our system is in a complete vacuum, and we have a way of keeping the gas in place (so that it doesn't expand into the vacuum). With nothing to transfer heat to in the vacuum, the system won't transfer heat to it.

Of course, there is still the problem of the container keeping the gas in place.

Whatever container keeping the gas in place must have an extremely low heat capacity, because in the limit of it going to zero, it will require no heat to keep its changing temperature the same as that of the gas.

Another way would be to somehow reduce the temperature of the container externally at the same rate as the temperature of the gas does as it expands.